# File-specific JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now, in my Rails project, I have in `app/views/layouts` the file `application.html.erb`

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= yield :javascript_includes %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

This includes all the JavaScript files in `public/javascripts` in all HTML pages.

Now, I have in `app/views/dogs` the file `new.html.erb`. I want to include a JavaScript file that is specific to this HTML file. Where should I put the JavaScript, and how can I include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new javascript file in `/app/assets/javascripts` then include it on your `dogs/new` page with `<%= javascript_include_tag "dogs.js" %>`.

Comment: So it will not be in the `head` section of the HTML page. Is that the "correct" thing to do?

Comment: It can be wherever you want depending on what you're doing.  The best place is usually right before `</body>` but that's outside the scope of this question/answer.  Use `content_for(:head)` to put it in `<head>`.